# Finding colour of specific pixel on UIImageView

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uiimageview, uiimage

I am working on a paint application and want to build the undo manager. I store the pixel co-ordinate value of each location where the user draws but I also want to store the old pixel colour of the point where the user has drawn so that I can undo it to appropriate colour. But I am unable to do so. Can anybody help.

Here is the code I am currently using to get the pixel colour:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.tempDrawImage.frame.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
int bpr = CGBitmapContextGetBytesPerRow(context);
unsigned char * data = CGBitmapContextGetData(context);
if (data!=NULL)
{
    int offset = bpr*(lastPoint.y)+ 4*(lastPoint.x);
    NSLog(@"Red : %d",data[offset+0]);
    NSLog(@"Green : %d",data[offset+1]);
    NSLog(@"Blue : %d",data[offset+2]);
}
```

Comment: may be this question helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21028952/how-to-get-the-pixel-color-values-of-custom-image-inside-imageview-ios

Comment: and pascs answer is too clear

Comment: But parcs answer still return only 0.

Comment: your question and its description both doesn't match `Finding colour of specific pixel on UIImageView` and your code shows that you are getting the specific pixel. Now If you want to draw something on the Image I suggest you to first make A copy And then revert on it when redrawing or undo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best solution for this to use [UIImage+ColorAtPixel](https://github.com/ole/OBShapedButton/tree/master/UIImage+ColorAtPixel) category class of `UIImage`. I have used this, very nice and perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the copy of your image every time before image drawing modifications begin (for example just before a user taps on the screen).